# Stata loop over filenames

Tags: stata

I'm trying to loop over filenames `t3`, `t6`, `t9`, and `t12` to change variable names. Right now I have

```
foreach wave in 3 6 9 12 {;

    use ~/Desktop/Replication/t`wave';

    rename tcarval1 tcarval1`wave';

};
```

but Stata says

> file /Users/abc/Desktop/Replication/t.dta not found

Is there a reason it's not picking up the number from the loop?

Answer (score 1):

**Are you running the code line-by-line?**

I can't reproduce your error, but this works fine:

```
foreach wave in 3 6 9 12 {
    display "~/Desktop/Replication/t`wave'"
}
```

This will also run:

```
#delimit ;
foreach wave in 3 6 9 12 { ;
    display "~/Desktop/Replication/t`wave'" ;
} ;
#delimit cr
```

### Edit (digressing)

I knew about `# delimit ;` but I never use it, which is how the ill advice (questioned by @William Lisowski) originally came up (not present anymore).

Running this:

```
#delimit ;
foreach wave in 3 6 9 12 { 
    display "~/Desktop/Replication/t`wave'" 
} 
#delimit cr
```

outputs nothing. Stata read the whole thing, never reached the expected delimiter `;`, and exited.

The following

```
#delimit ;
foreach wave in 3 6 9 12 { 
    display "~/Desktop/Replication/t`wave'" 
} 
;
#delimit cr
```

gives

> program error:  code follows on the same line as open brace
>
> r(198);

which is more or less equivalent to the following when we **don't** use `#delimit ;`:

```
foreach wave in 3 6 9 12 { display "~/Desktop/Replication/t`wave'" }
```

and that's illegal.

Something similar happens with

```
#delimit ;
foreach wave in 3 6 9 12 { 
    display "~/Desktop/Replication/t`wave'" ;
} 
#delimit cr
```

The following also gives an error

```
#delimit ;
foreach wave in 3 6 9 12 { ;
    display "~/Desktop/Replication/t`wave'" 
} 
#delimit cr
```

albeit different:

> unexpected end of file
>
> r(612);

Now it is equivalent to

```
foreach wave in 3 6 9 12 {
```

, incomplete code for all Stata knows. Stata expects something after the open brace, but never sees it. It complains.

Summarizing, Stata treats each of the three lines as different "commands", and requires `;` to be present. But the first line is special, in the sense that `{` must be followed by something, be that at least a closing `}`.

Comment: It's possible the `;`s are due to using `#delim ;` in his do-file because without it, the `foreach ...{;` raises an error message. If I include `#delim ;` I can run code like his without his error. And I can run code like his a line at a time without his error.

Comment: You can only run it line-by-line interactively (without `# delimit ;`). Line-by-line from a .do file would fail unless. With `# delimit ;` it executes fine if running the whole code from a .do file. All in all, the emphasis must be in the original poster providing a reproducible example.

Comment: My comment was in response to your suggestion that he get rid of the `;`s, which you subsequently removed from your answer. I saw no reason to do so. I agree that his example does not reproduce on either your system or mine, and by omitting the `#delim ;` was incomplete. Perhaps something else that was omitted led to the problem, so he should start small and enlarge until he produces something that fails.

Comment: Indeed @William, that only caused confusion and I deleted it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this:

```
cd "~/Desktop/Replication"

foreach wave in 3 6 9 12 {
    use t`wave'.dta
    rename tcarval1 tcarval1`wave'
}
```